# MaterializeCSS and Rails Forms elements -> hidden inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm using rails 7 and materializeCSS.

When I add a `collection_select` or `check_box` to the form object (`form.check_box :active` for example) the check box is rendered as: `<input name="user[active]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off">`

Rails code:

`<%= form.check_box :active %>`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended by solving it by adding

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
 /* your style */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
 /* your style */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
 /* your style */
}
```

to `application.scss`